# Dynamically access property nested in anonymous type within LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, linq-to-entities, anonymous-types

I am executing a lengthy LINQ query on my EF-mapped DB entity classes that is treated by Linq2Sql and ends up with an anonymous type:

```
...
.Where(e => ...)
.Join(..., (outer, inner) => new {
    outer.Object1,
    outer.TempId,
    Object2 = inner
})
```

So far, so good - up to that point, everything will nicely be translated to SQL and run on the DB. I can iterate over the anonymously typed objects, at which point only the very data contained therein will be materialized on the C# side.

**However:** I now need to perform one last filtering step that will reduce the data set, which is why it should run on the DB, as well. I need to compare a property on `Object1` and `Object2`.

**The name of this property is passed in to my method as a string.**

Under normal circumstances, this wouldn't be a problem. I could simply access the anonymous object via reflection - even if it means I have to get the anonymous type by means of `.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]` on my enumerable.

However, I need to make sure everything's typesafe here, so the ensuing `foreach` will let me iterate over and work with instances of the anonymous type. Therefore, creating a filter expression is not straightforward as I cannot specify a type for [`Lambda<TDelegate>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Lambda__1_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Linq_Expressions_ParameterExpression__) - it would have to be a `Func<..., Boolean>`, where `...` is my anonymous type!

I have thought about creating a project function instead that takes an instance of the type that `Object1` and `Object2` in my anonymous type belong to - say, `ObjectData`, - and returns the property value. This would, of course, be feasible:

```
var prm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ObjectData), "obj");
var projectionExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<ObjectData, int>>(Expression.Property(prm, myPropertyName), prm);
```

But then I'm not sure where to apply them - I'd need some kind of a "single-item select", that just projects one value to another by means of a projection expression and that will play well with EF's LINQ to Entities/SQL generation - something like (pseudocode, with an imaginary `PROJECT` function) this:

```
.Select(info => new {
    info.Object1,
    info.TempId,
    info.Object2,
    Value1 = PROJECT(info.Object1, projectionExpr),
    Value2 = PROJECT(info.Object2, projectionExpr)
})
```

**How do I get my final filter into the story?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more like a case for [dynamic linq](https://dynamic-linq.net/download). With that library, it should be possible to add something like this to your query:

```
.Where(e => ...)
.Join(..., (outer, inner) => new {
    outer.Object1,
    outer.TempId,
    Object2 = inner
})
.Where($"Object1.{myPropertyName} == Object2.{myPropertyName}");
```

Comment: We actually have that library in our project already, and I always wondered in what situations I would want to use it, seeing that I could fulfil virtually everything I wanted with some reflection + `System.Linq.Expression` trickery. So this is the day ... works like a charm, thank you.